# How can I prevent a portable Chromium from saving settings to the hard disk?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, chromium

I have a USB flash drive with a nightly version of Chromium on it. It's meant to run on somebody's computer without the need of installing Chromium on it.

The problem is that it's still saving the *settings* on the user's hard disk (e.g. in `C:\Users\...\AppData\...` on Vista). I'd like to keep the user's computer completely clean.

How can I prevent this storage? Is there a way to make Chromium either not save any settings, or save the settings on the flash drive instead?

Comment: Changing %UserProfile% to a directory on the flash drive before starting Chromium might do it.

Comment: @user55325: Searching for `UserProfile` revealed the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should have searched a little more, since I eventually found the answer [here](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory):

> You can also start Chromium with a custom user data directory in order
>   to run multiple instances at the same time.
>
> **Windows**
>
> To do this, add the `--user-data-dir` flag to `chrome.exe`, like this:
>
> `chrome.exe --user-data-dir=c:\foo`

So for my scenario I have to run:

```
chromium\chrome.exe --user-data-dir=%cd%\userdata
```

after creating a directory `userdata` on my flash drive. (This command is inside a batch file located in the same directory as the `userdata` directory is located.)